A "boundary" series whose convergence is undecidable
It is known that there is no "boundary" between convergence and divergence for infinite series; that is, given a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of positive reals such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, we can find another sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n/a_n=0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges as well (and likewise for divergent series). My question is as follows (and I suspect that the answer is no): is there a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of positive reals such that for any sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of positive reals:

If $b_n/a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges;
If $b_n/a_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges;
The convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is undecidable in ZFC?

I don't think it's too hard to construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ whose convergence is undedicable - for example, let $P$ be a proposition whose truth is undecidable in ZFC, and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set $a_n=1/n$ if $P$ is true and $a_n=2^{-n}$ otherwise. I'm not sure if you can construct $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to satisfy the other two conditions, though.

Despite being undecidable in ZFC, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ either converges or diverges.
If it converges, then there is a sequence of positive numbers $b_n$ such that $b_n/a_n \to +\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ also converges (although one or both of these facts may be undecidable).
If it diverges, there there is a sequence of positive numbers $b_n$ such that $b_n/a_n \to 0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ also diverges (although again, one or both of these facts may be undecidable).
In your example where $P$ is undecidable, you could take $b_n = 1/(n \log (n+1))$ if $P$ is true and $b_n = n 2^{-n}$ if $P$ is false.

Even #1 and #2 alone are incompatible. For positive series, if $\sum_n a_n$ diverges, then one can find $b_n$ with $b_n/a_n\to0$ for which $\sum_n b_n$ still diverges; so #1 implies that $\sum_n a_n$ converges. Similarly, if $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then one can find $b_n$ with $b_n/a_n\to\infty$ for which $\sum_n b_n$ still converges; so #2 implies that $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.
